# How to add datalabels to ng2-charts in angular

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

Hello I want to use datalabels in my chartOptions of the Angular project with ng2-charts:

as per documentation I added config object like this:

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective | undefined

  public pieChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'top',
      },
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          if (ctx.chart.data.labels) {
            return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
          }
        },
      },
    }
  };
```

in the template:

```
    <canvas baseChart
            [plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
            [data]="pieChartData"
            [type]="pieChartType"
            [options]="pieChartOptions"
            >
    </canvas>
```

https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#PieChart

the error I am getting is:

Type '{ legend: { display: true; position: "top"; }; datalabels: { formatter: (value: any, ctx: any) => any; }; }' is not assignable to type '_DeepPartialObject<PluginOptionsByType>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'datalabels' does not exist in type '_DeepPartialObject<PluginOptionsByType>'.ts(2322)

I am using:

"chart.js": "^3.3.2",
"chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^1.0.0",
"ng2-charts": "3.0.0",

and angular:

"@angular/cdk": "12.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~12.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~12.1.0",

Answer (score 0):

You should add your plugins to the chart in order to use it properly:

in your HTML add the following to your Canvas:

```
[plugins]="pieChartPlugins"
```

And in your Typescript import and define your plugin array:

```
import DatalabelsPlugin from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
...
 
public pieChartPlugins = [ DatalabelsPlugin ];
```

Comment: I have tried this and I am getting the error:   Type 'Record<string, unknown>[]' is not assignable to type 'Plugin<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, AnyObject>[]'. I will add the way I initialize my chart maybe the problem is there ...

Comment: Did you run `npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels`?

Comment: yes I have installed chartjs plugins